# Get all rows and apply sum on a column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with four columns and 5 rows, I want all the 5 rows with sum of one column. Is it possible in MySQL?

```
name id  rank points
sam  1    4     34
ram  2    6     45
hari 3    1     87
kum  4    7     56
raj  5    5     20
```

What I need is name id rank points and **sum of points** where rank above 4.

**Expected result**

```
name id  rank points sum 
ram  2    6     45    121
kum  4    7     56
raj  5    5     20
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could give the SQL DML. At the same time, it is possible only using a different query in SQL. You cannot combine them I believe.

Comment: It is not possible, You can not have a value in only one row

Comment: I am using mysql @ praveen.  Null in other columns is also acceptable. i dont want to hit db two times for same table data

Comment: Did I say you are using MSSQL?

Comment: You need to use another query like this: `SELECT SUM(\`points\`) FROM \`users\` WHERE \`rank\` > 4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . .

```
select name, id, rank, points,
       (select sum(t2.points) from t t2 where t2.rank > 4) as `sum`
from t
where rank > 4;
```

This puts the `sum` on each row, but that seems like a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 1):

For you and others, the DML & DDL I used is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `name` varchar(5),
  `id` int,
  `rank` int,
  `points` int
);

INSERT INTO users (
  `name`, `id`, `rank`, `points`
) VALUES (
  'sam', 1, 4, 34
), (
  'ram', 2, 6, 45
), (
  'hari', 3, 1, 87
), (
  'kum', 4, 7, 56
), (
  'raj', 5, 5, 20
);
```

For doing it, you **need** to have a separate query:

```sql
SELECT SUM(`points`) FROM `users` WHERE `rank` > 4
```

And I would suggest you to append this at the end.

```sql
SELECT *, (
  SELECT SUM(`points`) FROM `users` WHERE `rank` > 4
) AS `sum` FROM `users` WHERE `rank` > 4
```

The above will give this as output:

```
+------+----+------+--------+-----+
| name | id | rank | points | sum |
+------+----+------+--------+-----+
|  ram |  2 |    6 |     45 | 121 |
|  kum |  4 |    7 |     56 | 121 |
|  raj |  5 |    5 |     20 | 121 |
+------+----+------+--------+-----+
```

**Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1dd6260/5**